# Disable Integrity constraint violation: 1048

Tags: mysql

I have a table which has a column configured as NOT NULL.

I would like to insert a record with a NULL value for that column.

How do I temporarily disable this check?  I am thinking something like `SET foreign_key_checks = 0;`, but not for foreign key checks but NOT NULL checks.

Comment: NOT NULL means it cannot be null even if gipsy kids fall from the skies.

Comment: Come on, I searched the documentation and couldn't find the ability to do so, and asked the question.  You might think it is a bad idea, but it is not a bad question.

Comment: It is a bad question because it would be terribly inconsistent to come across NULL values in a column whose definition prohibits NULL values and you asked just how to do that.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp.  That was the point.  I wanted this particular record to be terribly inconsistent.

Comment: I see. In my opinion, in programming one should always aim towards maximum consistency for the sake of quality and maintainability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A column constraint is not a foreign key. You can't disable column constraints.
If the value must not be `NULL`, it's been set to that for a reason.

If you were able to disable it and re-enable it after adding a `NULL` value, it would still be invalid for the column.

Either change the column settings to allow `NULL` or insert an empty value instead (`UPDATE table SET column = '';`).

Keep your schema valid and normalized!

Comment: Thanks Dan,  It is normalized for everything but this one record.  The table is a "users" table, and this record is the one and only root user.  I will but empty string values in there as you recommend, but it is not as accurate as null.

Comment: Define `accurate` ;-) If you need exceptions for specific rows, the schema is propably not normalized. Imagine having more than 1 root user.

Comment: Accurate wasn't the correct word.  NULL is less misleading.  I could and will include a value but this one particular user doesn't necessary need one.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user1032531 May I ask what data is inside the column?

Comment: All users are assigned to a particular account, and could only access data related to that account.  The root user has access to all accounts.  Users include an "accounts_id" column.  Putting a value in for the root user is misleading.

Comment: You could put the relation between account_id and user_id in a seperate table and just don't insert a row for root. This would result in a NULL value if left joined + the ability of a many2many / many2one relatino.

Comment: Yes I could, but I don't know if it is worth it.  I will either go with 0 (and disable FK when I insert it), or create an account called "root" or something, and use that value.